# Specify what goes into $matches in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have been researching this for a half hour and still can't figure it out. I am sure it is simple.

I want to match an id but only if it has "ID: " in front.

```
<?php
$string1 = "Payment: 1474";
$string2 = "Payment ID: 1474";

preg_match('/ID: ([0-9]){1,7}$/', $string1, $matches);

//array(0){} Good! This is the expected result.

preg_match('/ID: ([0-9]){1,7}$/', $string2, $matches);

//array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "ID: 1474" [1]=> string(1) "4" }
//I am glad it finds a match, but I want matches[0] to be only the id, 1474

?>
```

In other words, I need to find a match but I also need to specify what goes into the array.

Since I am having trouble learning this, I would appreciate if you don't just answer with code but also explain what it does. Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the repeat count INSIDE the parentheses.

Comment: Note that it'll be in `$matches[1]`, not `$matches[0]`.

Comment: To expand on what @DavidKiger said, it will never be in `$matches[0]` as that matches the entire [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/ID: ([0-9]{1,7})$/', $string2, $matches);
```

In your code, the capture group was just matching one character. This matches 1-7 numbers inside the capture group.

Comment: Thanks! so for each group of parentheses, another item is added to the $matches array?

Comment: Yes, but once again note that the entire matched string is in `$matches[0]`, so your first parenthetical will be `$matches[1]`.

Comment: @hellohellosharp Exactly. But if you have a repeat operator on a parenthesis group, only one item item (the first or last match, depending on the implementation I think) is added to `$matches`, no matter how many times it's repeated.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses capture a part of the matched expression and store it in $matches[1]. This is the est way to get exactly what you want. Just move the closing paren to the right of the `{1,7}` part:

```
preg_match("/ID: (\d{1,7})/", $string2, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

For arguments sake:

```
  preg_match('/(?<=ID: )[0-9]{1,7}$/', $string2, $matches);
```

(`(?<=)` is a lookbehind operator which only looks whether the match is preceded by this, but it is not actually part of the resulting match. I however struggle to think of a valid reason why it *has* to be in the `0`'th index.... Just say `$id=$matches[1]`, and you have your data?

Comment: Thanks! Forgive me...it doesn't need to be in the 0th index at all, just needs to be in there.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now, I overlooked the part about only the first number being in your match. Well, @Barmar is right in this case, just look at this as a quaint gimmick ;)